# visualbasic tcp how to write line by line

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I want to make a program where another user can send data to a pc.
I need a username and password, but the problem is I don't find code to accept 2 tcp data stuff.

I have the variables `password` and `username`, but when I start all the text is read into the `username` variable. I need it to be split.

Here is my code.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim mysyqlcon As MySqlConnection
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim TCPServer As Socket
    Dim TCPListenerz As TcpListener
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Try
            Dim rcvbytes(TCPServer.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            TCPServer.Receive(rcvbytes)
            username = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Try
            Dim rcvbytes2(TCPServer.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            TCPServer.Receive(rcvbytes2)
            password = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes2)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Label1.Text = username
        Label2.Text = password
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TCPListenerz = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1000)
        TCPListenerz.Start()
        TCPServer = TCPListenerz.AcceptSocket()
        TCPServer.Blocking = False
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: TCP guarantees that the bytes stuffed into the stream at one end will fall out the other end in the same order and without loss or duplication. Expect nothing more, certainly not support for entities larger than a byte. You need to use the value returned by [`Receive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine the number of bytes received, assemble a useful message from the bytes that dribble in, and provide some means to separate the username from the password.

Comment: Improved grammar and spelling. Added relevant tag, removed irrelevant one.